# How to load (.m) file with Glui opengl?

Tags: opengl, glui

I have looked through the examples in the Glui package, but I need help with loading (.m) file which is 3D model
this is the sample codes....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void createMenu(void);
void menu(int value);
void disp(void);

static int win;
static int menid;
static int submenid;
static int primitive = 0; // global variable for the geometric primitive

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  // normal initialisation
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE);
  glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);

  win = glutCreateWindow("GLUT MENU");

  // put all the menu functions in one nice procedure
  createMenu();

  // set the clearcolor and the callback
  glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

  // register your drawing function
  glutDisplayFunc(disp);

  // enter the main loop
  glutMainLoop();

  return 1;
}

//#define USE_SUB_MENU

void createMenu(void){

//#ifdef USE_SUB_MENU

    //  step 1: Create a submenu, this has to be done first.
  submenid = glutCreateMenu(menu); // pass the function "menu" to glutCreateMenu

  // Add sub menu entry
  glutAddMenuEntry("Teapot", 2);
  glutAddMenuEntry("Cube", 3);
  glutAddMenuEntry("Torus", 4);


  // step 2: Create the main menu, this menu becomes the current menu
  menid = glutCreateMenu(menu);

  // Create an entry
  glutAddMenuEntry("Clear", 1);

  glutAddSubMenu("Draw", submenid);
  // Create an entry
  glutAddMenuEntry("Quit", 0);

  // Let the menu respond on the right mouse button
  glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

//#else
  menid = glutCreateMenu(menu);

  // Create an entry
  glutAddMenuEntry("Clear", 1);
  glutAddMenuEntry("Teapot", 2);
  glutAddMenuEntry("Cube", 3);
  glutAddMenuEntry("Torus", 4);
  // Create an entry
  glutAddMenuEntry("Quit", 0);

  // Let the menu respond on the right mouse button
  glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

//#endif
}

void disp(void){
  // Just clean the screen
    // this has to be called everytime when you draw sth
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // draw what the user asked
  if(primitive == 1){ // clear the screen
    glutPostRedisplay();
  }else if(primitive == 2){ // draw the teapot
    glutWireTeapot(0.5);
  }else if(primitive == 3){ // draw the cube
    glutWireCube(0.5);
  }else if(primitive == 4){ // draw the torus
    glutWireTorus(0.3,0.6,100,100);
  }
  glFlush();
}


void menu(int value){
    if(value == 0){ // the user clicks 'quit'
    glutDestroyWindow(win);
    exit(0);
  }else{
    primitive=value; // set the geometric primitive
  }

  // you would want to redraw now
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

I really don't know how to do T_T, requirment is to load .m files using opengl, glut, glui.... So, I need help to load it with opengl without crashing then done.

Comment: ".m" is really vague. Where did you get it? How is it formatted? What have you tried? There's no model format that I know of that uses the ".m" extension. (Just the Objective C source :P). Also glui hasn't been updated in years and you really shouldn't be using it.

Comment: I know but I have no choice but to use it, since it is the requirement in the school assignment. or Glut also will do.

Comment: Okay. Lets start with what you know about the ".m" format. I assume they give you information about it. (I suspect it's just an arbitrary extension chosen for your assignment). The way you asked your question is the reason your getting down voted. Edit you question to show us what you tried and why you think it should work, give us more information about what's required and what's given. If the assignment allows it use freeglut (updated glut pretty much).

Comment: yeah, i got like bunny.m, gargoyle.m,..... I also found a forum (http://www.gamedev.net/topic/471700-saving-an-opengl-mesh-file-in-c/) but I don't know how to use it T_T.....

Comment: That's not a standardized extension that their talking about there. How does your .m files look? text based? If it's binary they need to have given you some more information.

Comment: this is the file provided https://www.dropbox.com/s/biblh7v510zw0hy/bunny.m

Comment: It's very similar to to obj files. You can look at how their read so long.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a parser for your .M files.

I couldn't find a spec anywhere so I've taken a guess at the format:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using namespace glm;

struct Vertex
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 normal;
};

vector< Vertex > LoadM( istream& in )
{
    vector< Vertex > verts;

    map< int, vec3 > positions;
    map< int, vec3 > normals;

    string lineStr;
    while( getline( in, lineStr ) )
    {
        istringstream lineSS( lineStr );
        string lineType;
        lineSS >> lineType;

        // vertex
        if( lineType == "Vertex" )
        {
            int idx;
            float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
            lineSS >> idx >> x >> y >> z;
            positions[ idx ] = vec3( x, y, z );
        }

        // face
        if( lineType == "Face" )
        {
            int indexes[ 3 ];
            int idx;
            lineSS >> idx >> indexes[0] >> indexes[1] >> indexes[2];

            // http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal
            vec3 U( positions[ indexes[1] ] - positions[ indexes[0] ] );
            vec3 V( positions[ indexes[2] ] - positions[ indexes[0] ] );
            vec3 faceNormal = normalize( cross( U, V ) );

            for( size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j )
            {
                Vertex vert;
                vert.position = vec3( positions[ indexes[j] ] );
                vert.normal   = faceNormal;
                verts.push_back( vert );
            }
        }
    }

    return verts;
}
```

Used in context:

[image: bunny]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/component_wise.hpp>  
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

struct Vertex
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 normal;
};

vector< Vertex > LoadM( istream& in )
{
    vector< Vertex > verts;

    map< int, vec3 > positions;

    string lineStr;
    while( getline( in, lineStr ) )
    {
        istringstream lineSS( lineStr );
        string lineType;
        lineSS >> lineType;

        // parse vertex line
        if( lineType == "Vertex" )
        {
            int idx = 0;
            float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
            lineSS >> idx >> x >> y >> z;
            positions.insert( make_pair( idx, vec3( x, y, z ) ) );
        }

        // parse face line
        if( lineType == "Face" )
        {
            int indexes[ 3 ] = { 0 };
            int idx = 0;
            lineSS >> idx >> indexes[0] >> indexes[1] >> indexes[2];

            // http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal
            vec3 U( positions[ indexes[1] ] - positions[ indexes[0] ] );
            vec3 V( positions[ indexes[2] ] - positions[ indexes[0] ] );
            vec3 faceNormal = normalize( cross( U, V ) );

            for( size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j )
            {
                Vertex vert;
                vert.position = vec3( positions[ indexes[j] ] );
                vert.normal   = faceNormal;
                verts.push_back( vert );
            }
        }
    }

    return verts;
}

// mouse state
int btn;
ivec2 startMouse;
ivec2 startRot, curRot;
ivec2 startTrans, curTrans;

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
    if( button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
    {
        btn = button;
        startMouse = ivec2( x, y );
        startRot = curRot;
    }
    if( button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
    {
        btn = button;
        startMouse = ivec2( x, y );
        startTrans = curTrans;
    }
}

void motion( int x, int y )
{
    y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
    ivec2 curMouse( x, y );
    if( btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON )
    {
        curRot = startRot + ( curMouse - startMouse );
    }
    else if( btn == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON )
    {
        curTrans = startTrans + ( curMouse - startMouse );
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

vector< Vertex > model;
void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = w / h;
    // "pan"
    glTranslatef( curTrans.x / w * 2, curTrans.y / h * 2, 0 );
    gluPerspective( 60, ar, 0.1, 20 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -10 );

    glPushMatrix();
    // apply mouse rotation
    glRotatef( curRot.x % 360, 0, 1, 0 );
    glRotatef( -curRot.y % 360, 1, 0, 0 );

    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );

    // draw model
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &model[0].position );
    glNormalPointer( GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &model[0].normal );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.size() );
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );

    // draw bounding cube
    glDisable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glutWireCube( 7 );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// return the x/y/z min/max of some geometry
template< typename Vec >
pair< Vec, Vec > GetExtents
    ( 
    const Vec* pts, 
    size_t stride, 
    size_t count 
    )
{
    typedef typename Vec::value_type Scalar;
    Vec pmin( std::numeric_limits< Scalar >::max() );
    Vec pmax( std::min( std::numeric_limits< Scalar >::min(),
                        (Scalar)-std::numeric_limits< Scalar >::max() ) );

    // find extents
    unsigned char* base = (unsigned char*)pts;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i )
    {
        const Vec& pt = *(Vec*)base;
        pmin = glm::min( pmin, pt );
        pmax = glm::max( pmax, pt );
        base += stride;
    }

    return make_pair( pmin, pmax );
}

// centers geometry around the origin
// and scales it to fit in a size^3 box
template< typename Vec > 
void CenterAndScale
    (
    Vec* pts, 
    size_t stride, 
    size_t count,
    const typename Vec::value_type& size
    )
{
    typedef typename Vec::value_type Scalar;

    // get min/max extents
    pair< Vec, Vec > exts = GetExtents( pts, stride, count );

    // center and scale 
    const Vec center = ( exts.first * Scalar( 0.5 ) ) + ( exts.second * Scalar( 0.5f ) );

    const Scalar factor = size / glm::compMax( exts.second - exts.first );
    unsigned char* base = (unsigned char*)pts;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i )
    {
        Vec& pt = *(Vec*)base;
        pt = ((pt - center) * factor);
        base += stride;
    }    
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    ifstream ifile( "bunny.m" );
    model = LoadM( ifile );
    if( model.empty() )
    {
        cerr << "Empty model!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    CenterAndScale( &model[0].position, sizeof( Vertex ), model.size(), 7 );

    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMouseFunc( mouse );
    glutMotionFunc( motion );

    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    // set up "headlamp"-like light
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
    glEnable( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL );
    glColorMaterial( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE ) ;
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    GLfloat position[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position );

    glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT, GL_FILL );
    glPolygonMode( GL_BACK, GL_LINE );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D.... but i got one problem,.. it crashed once that bunny window shows up...

Comment: @user2987457: Edited.  I suspect `"bunny.m"` isn't in your current working directory.  Try replacing it with an absolute path to the file.

Comment: I just moved it to the same directory as .cpp, but still crashed T_T
https://www.dropbox.com/s/628zgrjjb5acwwb/test003.png

Comment: I used CodeBlocks, it crashed after the mesh viewer window pop-up.
But didn't show anything if i used Visual C++ 2012

Comment: Where does the debugger say it crashes?

Comment: @genpfault What are the compiler options needed to run this in Ubuntu?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: Something like `g++ main.cpp -o main -lGL -lGLU -lglut` might work.  Make sure you have the Mesa & FreeGLUT `dev` packages installed, not sure what they're called nowadays.

Comment: @genpfault I tried, but it shows screen shot in Linux Mint!

Comment: @genpfault It worked! It shows the screenshot at start, later changed to the model if clicked inside window.

Comment: @genpfault One little thing, how can I add zoom with it?